# C++ program - "Making Change" application yielding odd results

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, currency

I need to make a simple C++ program that asks the user to enter any amount of money, and then show the user how to pay the specified amount using the smallest number of  50,20,10,5,1 units of money. In the context of my program, the unit of money used is Rands.

Below is my code which makes sense to me, however I yield an unexpected output. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

```
//File: change.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int amount = 0;
int main(void){
    cout << "Enter a Rands Amount:\n";
    int fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones=0;
    cin >> amount;

    while ((amount - 50)>=0){
        fifties = fifties +1;
        amount = amount - 50;
    }
    cout << "R50 Notes: " << fifties << "\n";

    while ((amount - 20)>=0){
        twenties = twenties +1;
        amount = amount - 20;
    }
    cout << "R20 Notes: " << twenties << "\n";

    while((amount-10)>=0){
        tens = tens+1;
        amount = amount - 10;
    }
    cout << "R10 notes: " << tens << "\n";  

    while((amount-5)>=0){
        fives = fives+1;
        amount = amount - 10;
    }
    cout << "R5 coins: " << fives << "\n";  

    while((amount-1)>=0){
        ones = ones+1;
        amount = amount - 1;
    }
    cout << "R1 coins: " << ones << "\n";   

}
```

When executing this code with the input 93, i expect the following output:

-R50 Notes: 1
-R20 Notes: 2
-R10 notes: 0
-R5 coins: 0
-R1 coins: 3

instead, I receive the following output:

-R50 Notes: 1
-R20 Notes: 2089938002
-R10 notes: 32767
-R5 coins: 0
-R1 coins: 3

All help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
int fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones=0;
```

only initializes `ones`.  You need to initialize each of the other variables.

Comment: Oh great it works, thank you so much :) Is there a reason for the output i was receiving though? Because i had not initialised the fifties variable, however i received the correct output for that variable?

Comment: @MarkoVidalis: Uninitialized variables can contain any old random data so if it worked at all, it was purely coincidental.  Glad to have been of some help.